# Forms Authentication User.IsInRole() randomly not working in LogOn

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I was changing the default LogOn function in an MVC3 project to redirect a user to a certain page based on their `role` by using `User.IsInRole()`. When I was testing this out, the first couple users redirected as expected, but after that I had a couple that didn't redirect to where they are supposed to (they passed through all the statements and hit the default home index.) It seems completely random, sometimes my `admin` will be taken to the admin page, other times not.

My LogOn function:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if(Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && 
                returnUrl.StartsWith("/") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && 
                !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                if(User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                }
                else if(User.IsInRole("Employee"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
                }
                else if(User.IsInRole("Accounting"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Accounting");
                }
                // If the user is in none of those roles, send them to the home index
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
            if(user == null)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "You haven't been approved yet, or you are locked out.");
        }
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Looking at the IntelliTrace, it seems like sometimes it doesn't bother to query the database, for example, when it works I see `Execute Reader "dbo.aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetRolesForUser"` and when it doesn't I don't.

Does anyone know why `User.IsInRole()` would return false even if the user is in the role? Is there some form of cashing happening, why isn't it queering the database every time?

I know for sure the users are in the roles I am testing, and I know it is not trying to redirect to the return url, I also know that the role isn't being stored in any cookies. Any ideas would be appreciated, I'm sure I could go about this another way, however now I'm more interested in why this simple approach isn't working.

**Update**

I found that if i replace the `If(User.IsInRole(...` statements with a redirect to another action called sorting, and I add the if statements there, it works 100% of the time.

```
public ActionResult Sorting()
{
    if(User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("SuperAdmin"))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
    }
    else if(User.IsInRole("Employee"))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Employee");
    }
    else if(User.IsInRole("Accounting"))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Accounting");
    }
    // If the user is in none of those roles, send them to the home index
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

So apparently `User.Identity.Name` is not set (or will not return the user's name) until the `LogOn` function exits. Is this correct? I figured that after the `Membership.ValidateUser` was called the user was authenticated, apparently not.

So at what point after `Membership.ValidateUser()` is called, will the `User.IsInRole()` going to work correctly? Is is after the cookie is dropped, or what?

I suppose I could use `if(Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "Admin"))` since I do have the user's name from the model submitted. Do you think this is a better idea or just use the `Sorting` redirect like I did?

Comment: Nothing seem to be wrong here.. Try testing once again properly. You are not sure yourself here. You need to find out why your application is not working properly. You are confusing everyone including yourself.

Comment: I've actually had the same issue as you have Garrett (redirect based on login role inside of the `LogOn` action).  My solution was to simply query the db directly...it was easy and worked so why not.  What it looked like to me was the the Cookie wasn't set yet, but the added benefits of using `User.IsInRole("blah")` didn't seem worth the extra troubleshooting when a direct db query worked perfectly.  If this sounds like a viable option for you let me know and I'll post an example of the code as an answer so you can accept it!

Comment: @Jared, I'm starting to think it has to do with the cookie not being set. Take a look at my update, I purposed two other solutions. I'm more interested in the why it didn't work other than solutions. If you have evidence that it is the cookie, I will accept that as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the `LogOn` function is called, the incoming request has no authenticated user, the User object is null, it is not until a new request is made that the User object is populated. So when `User.IsInRole()` is called in the `LogOn`, `User` is `null`.

> In short, the User object is set earlier in the ASP.NET pipeline, long
>   before the requested ASP.NET page's code is executed. Now, on the
>   subsequent visit, the ASP.NET runtime will see the forms
>   authentication ticket and User.Identity.IsAuthenticated will be true,
>   but not on this request.
>   ...
>
> Also, you won't be able to get the username
>   from User.Identity.Name. Instead, use LoginControlID.Username.

http://forums.asp.net/post/1988606.aspx